# Why do imports work only when running without run configuration?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, I have one common module (called common.py) that I want to import from a few other files. It used to be working fine, until recently when I ran the program using Ctrl+Enter. Since then, I can now *only* run the code with Ctrl+Enter, using the normal run configuration doesn't recognize the imports; it says "unused import" and doesn't resolve references to methods in common.py. Here is the code in the file I'm trying to run:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as cl
from common import *

N = np.arange(5, 30, 1, int)

get_noiseless_eigenvalues(np.matrix([[1]]))
```

Both `np` and `get_noiseless_eigenvalues` aren't resolved by PyCharm, even though they are both present in common.py:

```
import numpy as np


def get_noiseless_eigenvalues(m: np.matrix):
    return [v for v in np.linalg.eigh(m)[1] if sum(v) == 0]
```

I checked that the directory is indeed still marked as *Sources Root*. What could be the problem here?

Edit: I checked the changes with git, turns out that an empty __init__.py was added in two locations; for now, I can at least run the program normally but I'm still wondering why this happened

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong here, but in general, don't use `*` imports to avoid confusion.

Comment: Make sure the `working directory` is correct in your run configuration

Comment: The addition of `__init__.py` changes a "directory" into a `Python Package`, which changes the rules for what can be imported. The Python docs have more info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages